# If a BJT can be modelled as a current-controlled current source, is there any limit to the load resistance?

Tags: bjt

I have read that a BJT can be treated as a current-controlled current source. I am guessing that it can't provide the same current to an indefinitely high resistance.  What is the maximum load resistance that it can provide current to?

Comment: There are always limits.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "compliance range", usually specified as a voltage between zero and supply minus saturation.

Answer (score 1):

The premise of the question is wrong. It would be correct to say that a BJT can sometimes be modeled as a current-controlled current source.

As far as "when" is concerned- it depends.

Answer (score 0):

The transistor creates no energy. It sources current into a load that provides the energy. In common emitter configuration, with a resistive load R connected to voltage V, the transistor will saturate at a current a bit less than V/R.